# In which order are the increment expressions on the right evaluated in the assignment statement? Is it undefined?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, comma-operator

I recently learnt about undefined behaviour in C, but this particular code was used in a site as an example for 'comma as an operator', and while I understand how y = x++ in line 2, I dont understand in what order the sub expressions in line 2 are evaluated. I think it is undefined behaviour, but I'm not sure,because the site didn't mention anything as such.

```
int main()
{
    int x = 10, y;

    y = (x++, printf("x = %d\n", x), ++x, printf("x = %d\n", x), x++);

    printf("y = %d\n", y);
    printf("x = %d\n", x);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
x = 11
x = 12
y = 12
x = 13
```

Comment: [This evaluation order and sequencing reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order) might be helpful.

Comment: Comma operator has left-to-right evaluation

Comment: @EdHeal He did not write this code, he found it online and wanted to understand it. No reason to be impolite.

Comment: Please post a link to the site where you found this 'code' so that future users of SO can avoid it.

Comment: Link to the site?

Comment: very sorry! can't seem to find it anymore... It was some site we friends came across casually in the library. As soon as I find it I'll post it here? @MartinJames

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not undefined behaviour.
You first increase x to 11, the print it, then increase it to 12 and print it, then increase it after evaluation, so x will be 13 and the whole expression will evaluate to 12.

This is caused due to the comma operator in C being a sequence point, which means it is guaranteed all side effects of previous evaluations will have been performed, and no side effect from subsequent evaluations have yet been performed.

Comment: You might like to add that this is because the comma operator introduces a "sequence point" in C, forcing an order of evaluation and side effects. If you use some of the other operators, such as multiplication, the behaviour will be undefined.

Comment: True. If the same values were passed to a function though, I think it would be undefined. In the ++ case here it's the same but += different vales would be interesting. But as @edheal implies, don't do it.

Comment: It might be worth noting that the commas in a function's argument list are not comma operators — there is no guaranteed left-to-right evaluation order for function arguments.